# Stratio Lucene for Cassandra

Tags: cassandra, lucene, stratio

I am newbie to Lucene. Just started. I have a few basic questions:

- How to view all the indexes that are created using Stratio Lucene ?
- How to delete indexes created using Stratio Lucene ?
- What is the difference between

  ```
  fields: {
       fld_1: {type: "string"},
       fld_2: {type: "text"}
   }
  ```

type: "string" and type: "text"

The reason I ask for the difference is because I ran in to an error when trying to create my very first lucene index. My column in Cassandra is something like this: 'fld_1 text', but when I tried to create and index on fld_1 like above it threw an exception

```
ConfigurationException: 'schema' is invalid : Unparseable JSON schema: Unexpected character ('}' (code 125)): was expecting either valid name character (for unquoted name) or double-quote (for quoted) to start field name
at [Source: {
fields: {
```

The Lucene index script:

```
CREATE CUSTOM INDEX lucene_index ON testTable ()
USING 'com.stratio.cassandra.lucene.Index'
WITH OPTIONS = {
   'refresh_seconds': '1',
   'schema': '{
fields: {
     fld_1: {type: "string"},
     fld_2: {type: "string"},
     id: {type: "integer"},
     test_timestamp: {type: "date", pattern: "yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss"}
  }
}'
};
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First : You can't view only the Stratio Lucene Index, below query will show you all the index

```
SELECT * FROM system."IndexInfo";
```

Second : You can delete index with `DROP INDEX index_name` command. i.e

```
DROP INDEX test;
```

Third : In Stratio Lucene Index, string is a not-analyzed text value and text is a language-aware text value analyzed according to the specified analyzer.

Which means that if you specify a field as string it will directly index and queried. But if you use text then it will first analyzed by your specified analyzer, default is `default_analyzer`(`org.apache.lucene.analysis.standard.StandardAnalyzer`) then index and queried.

Edited :

You have to first create a text field in cassandra then specified it when creating index.

Example :

```
ALTER TABLE testtable ADD lucene text;

CREATE CUSTOM INDEX lucene_index ON testTable (lucene) USING 'com.stratio.cassandra.lucene.Index'
WITH OPTIONS = {
   'refresh_seconds': '1',
   'schema': '{
     fields: {
         fld_1: {type: "string"},
         fld_2: {type: "string"},
         id: {type: "integer"},
         test_timestamp: {type: "date", pattern: "yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss"}
     }
   }'
};
```

For more : https://github.com/Stratio/cassandra-lucene-index/blob/branch-3.0.13/doc/documentation.rst#text-mapper

Comment: Thank you for responding. I updated the question with more information. I was following the example on the page you mentioned. Could you help explain that please?

Comment: Which cassandra and stratio index version are you using and put your schema that you are using to create index

Comment: I am using Cassandra 3.10 and stratio 3.10.

Comment: And the schema ??

Comment: By the way if you are using cassandra 3.10 why don't you use SASIIndex 
 https://docs.datastax.com/en/cql/3.3/cql/cql_using/useSASIIndex.html

Comment: You have to first create a text field in cassandra then specified it when creating index. Answer updated

Comment: Does the column name have to be lucene ?

Comment: no, it's just a dummy column to index and query for the index

Comment: In the example on the page they are not using a column like that. Is that due to a version change ?

Comment: I checked that After Cassandra and Stratio version 3.0, this dummy field removed. https://github.com/Stratio/cassandra-lucene-index/blob/branch-3.10/doc/documentation.rst#alternative-syntaxes